# Protractor: Window Size affects the size navigation, how to still look for the side navigation?

Tags: angularjs, testing, responsive-design, protractor, responsive

I am running a protractor tests that tries to click on one of the buttons on the side navigation.

Whenever I run these set of tests on a VM that runs all the tests it fails, with error meesage

> > UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (-140, 526)

My theory is that the side navigator gets hidden when the window is too small, because of its responsive nature.

Is there a way to find that link from the hidden side nav that got hidden from window being too small?

Comment: Have you tried this case manually for this size? How do you get to this side navigator?

Comment: The side nav, by default, should be displayed. but the environment the tests are being ran I believe has the window size too small, causing the side nav to be hidden.

Comment: you probably look for this `browser.manage().window().setSize(1200, 800);`, on the other side if it's running through VM and as a service you might have some limited options, i.e. you will need to change the VM resolution

Answer (score 0):

try to move mouse to the link and then click on it: 
`browser.actions().mouseMove(link).perform();` this may help in scrolling to the element if its hidden because of small browser window.

Comment: The whole side navigation gets hidden when the window is too small, it needs to click a button that would expand the side navigation.